# Google Maps yields a black map

Tags: android, google-maps

My google maps in android yields a black map. Is it because I have my files set up incorrectly (libraries in the wrong place etc.?)

Images:

The black screen:

[image]

The libraries and whatnot:

[image]
[image]

Are all my imported libraries correct?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sonnet"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.barcodelibrary.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sonnet.FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sonnet.Map"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sonnet.MapActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        </activity>


        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.stuff"
            android:value="stuff" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

there 'stuff' means my API key.

And my Logcat:

```
02-06 16:14:44.735: D/AndroidRuntime(5651): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-06 16:14:44.735: D/AndroidRuntime(5651): CheckJNI is OFF
02-06 16:14:44.745: D/dalvikvm(5651): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
02-06 16:14:44.745: D/dalvikvm(5651): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
02-06 16:14:44.755: D/dalvikvm(5651): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
02-06 16:14:44.755: D/dalvikvm(5651): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
02-06 16:14:44.895: D/AndroidRuntime(5651): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
02-06 16:14:44.895: D/AndroidRuntime(5651): Shutting down VM
02-06 16:14:44.895: D/dalvikvm(5651): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-06 16:14:44.895: I/AndroidRuntime(5651): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_1' failed
02-06 16:14:45.365: D/AndroidRuntime(5661): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
02-06 16:14:45.365: D/AndroidRuntime(5661): CheckJNI is OFF
02-06 16:14:45.375: D/dalvikvm(5661): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
02-06 16:14:45.375: D/dalvikvm(5661): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
02-06 16:14:45.385: D/dalvikvm(5661): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
02-06 16:14:45.385: D/dalvikvm(5661): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
02-06 16:14:45.515: D/AndroidRuntime(5661): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
02-06 16:14:45.525: D/dalvikvm(5661): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 163 unimplemented (abstract) methods
02-06 16:14:45.525: I/ActivityManager(432): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.sonnet/.FullscreenActivity} from pid 5661
02-06 16:14:45.565: D/AndroidRuntime(5661): Shutting down VM
02-06 16:14:45.565: D/jdwp(5661): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
02-06 16:14:45.565: D/dalvikvm(5661): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-06 16:14:45.565: D/dalvikvm(5672): Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-06 16:14:45.575: I/ActivityManager(432): Start proc com.example.sonnet for activity com.example.sonnet/.FullscreenActivity: pid=5672 uid=10031 gids={50031, 3003, 1015, 1028}
02-06 16:14:45.595: D/dalvikvm(122): GC_EXPLICIT freed 40K, 2% free 7478K/7584K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 29ms
02-06 16:14:45.625: D/dalvikvm(122): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 2% free 7478K/7584K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 27ms
02-06 16:14:45.655: D/dalvikvm(122): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 2% free 7478K/7584K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 28ms
02-06 16:14:45.995: D/libEGL(5672): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
02-06 16:14:46.035: D/libEGL(5672): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
02-06 16:14:46.055: D/libEGL(5672): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
02-06 16:14:46.095: D/OpenGLRenderer(5672): Enabling debug mode 0
02-06 16:14:46.125: I/ActivityManager(432): Displayed com.example.sonnet/.FullscreenActivity: +566ms
02-06 16:14:46.395: D/TilesManager(5672): Starting TG #0, 0x641e71c8
02-06 16:14:46.395: D/TilesManager(5672): new EGLContext from framework: 62607d38 
02-06 16:14:46.395: D/GLWebViewState(5672): Reinit shader
02-06 16:14:46.405: D/GLWebViewState(5672): Reinit transferQueue
02-06 16:14:48.705: W/ProcessStats(432): Skipping unknown process pid 5698
02-06 16:14:48.705: W/ProcessStats(432): Skipping unknown process pid 5709
02-06 16:14:48.705: W/ProcessStats(432): Skipping unknown process pid 5710
```

Comment: Please post your manifest and the logcat here. Thanks.

Comment: Done; there are no red error messages in my Logcat though...

Comment: Are you using the Google Play Services library?

Comment: Be sure to enable the google maps api with your project int the google api console

Comment: Uh I just found that I commented out the setContentView(stuff) line in the class that made the map and now I have a completely different problem. I'll research this myself, but thansk anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your manifest file, I see at least one problem:

1 - set the Google Play Services library for the `application` tag

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Then please make sure you have enabled the Google Maps API in the Google API console and that you are using the correct API Key according to the certificate you're using to sign the app.

All the procedure is described here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: For my first apps I always had problems with the API key/console.

Comment: I seem to be getting somewhere with your comment! The tablet is trying to update the Google play services so please wait. I think you just solved my problem, thanks.